# ROM 6582 (8382 is fake)

Tags: recovery-mode, tablet, rom

I have a tablet with android 4.4.2. That stayed without recovery, and hard reset doesn't work ( does nothing, don't delete anything, don't restarting anything)

I try to install cwm, and twrp with  uncletools, and mtktools . They also don't work .
Y search any recovery stock and nothing 
Y search any recovery custom but any work (or I don't know who to install) 
Please I need a stock rom of my tablet or recovery secure 
Or any idea, any help

[image]
[image]

Comment: Include the model/name of your tablet in the question..

Comment: In the images sau the name: 
Tablet_pc
Model: HD7 3g ( Hd73g 8gb 0606668)